# Apt-get fails because of libqtcore and libqtdbus4

Tags: raspbian, apt

On a fresh-today Raspbian build I did an apt-get update followed by an apt-get ugrade. I got the following error message:

```
sal@raspberrypi:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-network : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10+rpi1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11+rpi1 is installed
                  Depends: libqtdbus4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10+rpi1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11+rpi1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
sal@raspberrypi:~$
```

How can I fix this? It's currently impossible to apt-get install anything!

Comment: What happens when you try running apt-get -f install.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you have unmet dependencies, meaning that you are missing a piece of software (libqtcore4, libqtdbus4) that libqt4-network needs to run.  Like the error message says, try running `apt-get -f install libqt4-network` to fix this.

Check the [apt-get man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try using aptitude.
Aptitude has a stronger dependency resolve engine that apt-get, it tends to succeed where apt-get fails (or at least give you a few more options).

In case you don't have it:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
```